# Make CLion have C++ Source Files as .CC

Tags: c++, clion

In  CLion, is there a way to make all C++ source files have the `.cc` extension instead of the `.cpp` extension by default? For example, in a new project, there is a `main.cpp` file. I want it to be `main.cc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! You can rename file `main.cpp` or any other from context menu or by `Shift+F6` hot keys. 
[image]

Comment: The text of the answer is different from what the picture says. It's worth saying where to change the default extension: Settings window - Editor - Code style - C++ - New file extension tab.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new file, click a settings icon near the file type selector.

[image: New file dialog]

You will get to a settings window where you can set the extensions:

[image]